# PHP Loop for Checked Boxes is returning errors

Tags: php, checkbox, for-loop

I am currently trying to design a `for` loop to iterate through any 'checked' check boxes, and from that, use the value within the 'value' slot to run some queries. I am unfortunately struggling with this as the list of checkboxes are not pre-defined, they are dynamic from the database pending the users previous selection.

The loop actually works to present the items to be checked:

```
?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="$listing_id">
    <font size="+1" color="green"><?php echo"$list_name"; ?>:</font><br />
<?php
```

The listing ID within the value is what I need to work with in a mysql query before I run an update query. The `for` loop that's meant to work is:

```
foreach($_POST['option'] as $option) //loop through the checkboxes
{
    ...
}
```

The update query will work within this as its simply copied from somewhere else, I just need the 'Listing_ID' from the check boxes that are checked.

I ran this code to hopefully do some debugging:

```
if(empty($_POST['option'])){
    echo "no checkboxes checked.";
} else {
    if(!isset($_POST['option'])){
        echo "no set.";
    }
}
```

and it returns "no checkboxes checked."

I have now hit a grey area as to why this for loop isn't working (this was taken from another example on the internet).

Comment: What is your concrete question?

Comment: My 'concrete' question, is why is it appearing as so there are no checkboxes checked and how to get 'value' stored in each of the checkboxes if they are checked.

Comment: Your code examples appear to be a bit confused. And you should not be using the deprecated `font` tag anymore.

Comment: How you submit the form? Is the form html valid? Have you `var_dump()`ed the $_POST array?

Comment: Could you show us the html your first code block generates? Could you also use `var_dump($_POST)` before the debugging code to see what you get?

Comment: I do var_dump on the $_POST which returns - string(6) " Send ". If I removed this var_dump and then var_dump the options inside the for_loop, it returns this error: Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs//search_message.php on line 90 - line 90 is: foreach($_POST['option'] as $option).

Comment: The first code block generates a few results which are: <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="50"><font size="+1" color="green">Holiday Test:</font><br />, the only thing different for each is the value and of course the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try echoing out the `$option` in the loop to see what the value is and there you can see if there is something there.

```
foreach($_POST['option'] as $option) //loop through the checkboxes
{
    echo $option . "<br />";
}
```

Also make sure your form's method is set to `POST` or that it's action is pointed to the correct place. You also have an error in your input:

`<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="$listing_id">`

I assume you meant:

`<input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="<?php echo $listing_id;?>">`

**UPDATE:**

The error ended up not being in the code posted. Error was discovered in an if statement that always returned false that in-cased the code posted above.

Comment: Nothing is echoed, even though i've checked 2 boxes.

Comment: @BenLittle Try checking the HTML with firebug or the web inspector to see if there is in fact a value in the `value` attribute

Comment: I've checked in the web inspector, and yes there are values in there. These are the values I want to extract when on the checked checkboxes.

Comment: Have you tried a `var_dump($_POST['option']);`. If so what was the results.

Comment: Using the above returns NULL.

Comment: If that's the case, check your `<form>` tag. Make sure that the `action` is correct and the `method` is correct. And that the field is inputs are within the `<form>`

Comment: Ah now we're getting somewhere! This now returns array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "49" [1]=> string(2) "52" } - which is i've checked 2 boxes and the 49 and 52 are the values, yet, the $options are still not been echoed inside the forloop for some reason?.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4125/discussion-between-ben-little-and-brenjt)

Comment: for($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['option']); $i++){ echo $_POST['option'][$i]; }

Brenjt used this forloop to solve my problem!

Answer (score 1):

`empty($_POST['option'])` will return true, if either `$_POST['option']` is not set (same as `!isset($_POST['option'])` (!)) or an empty array.

If you need to debug what's going on, use `var_dump($_POST['option']);` to find out what has been submitted for the `option` checkboxes. I also suggest you do a `var_dump($_POST);` so you can see what has been submitted overall - e.g. in case the post action is not `post` you will immediatly notice). For HTML output:

```
echo '<pre>', htmlspecialchars(print_r($_POST, true)), '</pre>';
```

That should give you the information you're looking for. For each individual checkbox, you can do:

```
foreach($_POST['option'] as $option) //loop through the checkboxes
{
    var_dump($option);
}
```

Comment: `print_r($_POST['option'])` can also be helpful. And I have never trusted `empty()` on arrays.

Comment: using your first line of code, it returns this:
Array
(
    [user_id] => 20
    [message_subject] => Enquiry
    [msg] => test
    [send_message] =>  Send 
)

Comment: Ensure your checkboxes are part of the form, compare with this code, you can play around with it: http://codepad.viper-7.com/yEvZ2r

Answer (score 1):

First of all your code seems to be bugged to me. Maybe is just a typo but

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="$listing_id">
```

should be

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="option[]" value="<?=$listing_id?>"/>
```

Moreover using empty over an array is not good at all.